# Marvel Comics villain from the 60s/70s who was essentially a walking chemistry set?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification

**Plot Details/Summary**

The villain in question was notable for having a supply of chemicals on his costume.  I seem to recall several large test tubes in several rows on the chest of his costume.  I think it was six tubes in three rows, with the bottles on each side feeding into a tube apparatus.

The villain used those chemicals to create superpower like effects.  I seem to recall him mixing up something to make a super-cold effect or the like.  I cannot recall the full range of what he could create (and I'm certain it was a male villain), but the other powers were probably along those line (flame, gas, etc.)

I cannot remember who the villain was fighting, or if it was mid-to-late 60's-era or the 70's.  I'm almost certain it was no later than the 1970s.  I don't recall if the villain was a "one-off", but I'm fairly certain this was a minor villain that wasn't a recurring nemesis for any superhero.

**Timeframe**

As I mentioned before, 60's to 70's, probably not the latter 1970s if at all.

Comment: Aside from the not being a recurring nemesis, it sounds a lot like recurring Fantastic Four villain The Wizard (later of the Frightful Four): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(Marvel_Comics)

Answer (score 4):

The costume design may not match, but I have a strong suspicion it's **Diablo**

[image: Diablo wearing a pink costume with black highlights, pointy shoulders and "horns" on the head with green gloves and headdress]

[via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_(Marvel_Comics)) -

> Esteban Corazón de Ablo was a powerful alchemist in 9th century Saragossa, who sold his 
>   soul to the demon Mephisto to lengthen his life far beyond a human span.
>
> He employs a huge arsenal of alchemical potions that he discovered or
>   invented, and conceals within hidden pouches and pockets in his
>   costume. His alchemy can transmute elements through means unknown to
>   modern science. Although the range of his power is wide, the effects
>   are temporary unless Diablo provides a second dose, with the exception
>   being the elixir he used on Dragon Man. His mixtures include nerve gas
>   pellets, sleeping potions, a potion that renders a person inert by
>   lowering their body temperature, pellets that make people susceptible
>   to Diablo's hypnotic orders, and other potions and pellets that enable
>   him to transmute inorganic matter (stones to feathers, water to ice,
>   etc.), unleash explosive blasts, model surface features, give life to
>   inanimate objects, and create beings formed from the elements of
>   earth, fire, wind, and water called "elementals". He also has
>   alchemical potions which grant him teleportation for quick escapes.

Comment: From the Marvel Handbook; https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AjPJ.png

Answer (score 2):

Could it be Chemistro? I was unable to find an exact match on the costume, but it appears to have some variations.

[image: Chemistro I (Calvin Carr, I think)]

[image: I definitely didn't read this one.]

His first appearance was in 1973, but he was a recurring villain for Luke Cage so maybe not a match.